Computability, Totality, and Range of Two Turing Machine-Dependent Functions
I am analyzing two functions that are defined in terms of an effective enumeration $(M_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of all Turing machines. For a given input $x$, the notation $M_n(x) \downarrow$ means that the $n$-th Turing machine halts on input $x$, and $M_n(x) \uparrow$ means it does not halt.
The functions are defined as follows:
a) ( f(x) = )
\begin{cases} 
    1 & \text{if } \exists n \text{ such that } M_n(x) \downarrow, \\
    \uparrow & \text{if } \nexists n \text{ such that } M_n(x) \downarrow.
\end{cases}
b) ( f(x) = )

\begin{cases} 
    1 & \text{if } \forall n, M_n(x) \downarrow, \\
    \uparrow & \text{if } \neg(\forall n, M_n(x) \downarrow).
\end{cases}
I want to determine for each function the following properties:

Computability: Is the function computable? (Does there exist an algorithm that can compute the function for any input x?)
Totality: Is the function total? (Is it defined for all x∈N?)
Image: What is the range (set of values it actually produces)?

What I Have Thought So Far:
For the first function, it seems like there will always exist some Mn(x) that halts (e.g., a machine that halts immediately regardless of input). However, I’m unsure how this interacts with the undecidability of the halting problem.
For the second function, it seems unlikely that all Turing machines in the enumeration could halt on a given x, as the enumeration includes machines that loop infinitely. Thus, the condition ∀n:Mn(x)↓ may never be satisfied, suggesting the function might never return 1.
However, I am not entirely confident in these intuitions and would appreciate a rigorous justification for whether these functions are computable, total and what are their image.

Your intuition is correct. The first function is $1$ on every input, and the second function is $\uparrow$ on every input (since e.g. the fact that there is some $n$ corresponding to an algorithm that always immediately enters an infinite loop, regardless of input, will guarantee that it's never the case that $\forall n M_n(x)\downarrow$).
These are both partial computable functions, as one can easily cook up a Turing machine that returns $1$ on every input, or enters an infinite loop on every input. As for totality and range, these are very simple functions... just think through the definitions of these terms.
